# How to determine maximum tag length with v3 api?

Tags: youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We allow updating video tags in our application.  We've been having trouble determining how to correctly calculate the length of tags allowed.  Does anyone have any information on how to correctly calculate that?  For example how do spaces between tag words count toward the limit?  Something like "funny video"

Thanks!